# Paypal Error: Dispatch Error

Tags: paypal

I set up the RESTful API for PayPal in .NET, using their sample. It kinda works... I did manage to create a payment, but when I use the approval URL, it always says: dispatch error.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As I found out, the problem was: I was logged in with my paypal account. I used the same browser instance for reading documents, checking my PayPal account AND testing. Bad idea. PayPal assumes, that you want to pay with your merchant account.

Solution: use a different browser, or turn on your private mode in the browser. (You can also clear your cache, but as soon as you log in to PayPal to check the payment, you are back to square one.)